# Powershell - Regex - Fixed width file - Escape Characters

Tags: regex, powershell

While reading a fixed width file like this:

```
ABC       7112123207/24/16Smith                              Timpson                            Head Coach                                                            412-222-0000        00011848660    ELl CAAN HIGH SCHOOL                  325 N Peal AVE.                   Smith                         Timpson                       Head Coach                              COLORADO CITY            AZ 86021       01             FALL      MALE      07/29/16EQ15031                  1977904        BUDDY'S ALL STARS INC.                  BUDDY ALL STARS                                                                                                                             N                 V12V70R16                                1.00V12V70R16
```

I wish to escape the single whitespace, / and the apostrophe.

I tried my regex in Powershell like this:

```
 $Line | Select-String -Pattern "^(.*)[a-zA-Z0-9?\s?]" -AllMatches
```

I need the match values to read as:

ABC
12345607/24/16Joe (this split into three: 123456,07/24/16,Joe)
Smith
Head Trainer
Buddy's Box

I'm trying to add the slices to a csv assigning each one to a header. For instance:

```
$csh.USER_GROUP = $line.Substring(0,10).Trim() 
$csh.ORDER_NUMBER = $line.Substring(10,8).Trim()        
$csh.ORDER_ENTRY_DATE=$line.Substring(18,8).Trim()
$csh.CONTACT_FIRST=$line.Substring(26,35).Trim()
$csh.CONTACT_LAST=$line.Substring(61,35).Trim()
$csh.CONTACT_TITLE=$line.Substring(96,35).Trim()
$csh.CONTACT_EMAIL= $line.Substring(131,35).Trim()
$csh.CONTACT_PHONE=$line.Substring(166,20).Trim()
$csh.SCHOOL_ID=$line.Substring(186,15).Trim() 
} | convertto-csv | select-object -skip 1 | out-file temp.csv
```

Now, given that there are empty spaces and repeating elements, it is erring that duplicate keys are not allowed. Is there an elegant alternative?

Comment: Why are you using RegEx if it's fixed width? Why not just use `$Line.SubString()` to get the various columns? Or will the column widths vary?

Comment: the column widths vary crazily and am reading at least 4000 rows.

Comment: How about: `$Line -split "\s{2}"|?{$_}|%{$_.trim() -split '(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d)' -join ','}`

Comment: Thanks. Works cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match using two or more spaces as a delimiter:

```
if ($Line -match '(\S.*?)  +(.{6})(.{8})(.*?)  +(.*?)  +(.*?)  +(.*)') {
    $whatsit = $matches[1]
    $index = $matches[2] 
    $date = $matches[3]
    $name1 = $matches[4]
    $name2 = $matches[5]
    $position = $matches[6]
    $place = $matches[7]
} else {
    echo "Bad line $Line"
}
```

Comment: It's not clear whether you need further assistance, also to preserve spaces in comments use backticks around the text: `\`some text\``

Comment: Awesome. Worked. I have a line like: ` ABC      12345607/24/16Joe                             Smith                            Head Trainer   BUDDY'S Box                                                            423542312.`  (with 4 tabs worth of white space before the last item; and in fact this space should be filled as another item with NULL) I tried to add an extra space before the + but didn't work

Comment: As you can see the backticks don't work if there's a space right after the opening one, so I can't see the actual data. Also it's not clear why there should be a null item. Can you show another line that has something in that place?

Comment: I updated $line in the question for your reference. sorry for the confusion. By null, I mean reading this file and the larger space in between must count as a column, and the value I should get is empty (entering null into the DB).

Comment: This data *certainly* looks every column starts at a predefined position on each line, so you can simply use string slicing: `$Line.substring(0,10).trim()`, `$Line.substring(10,8).trim()`, and so on. Are absolutely sure this is not the case?

Comment: Yes sir, it is. Worked perfect. :)

Comment: Please refer to the updated question about inserting the rows into csv.